# Cordova FileTransfer.upload() fails on iOS

Tags: cordova, https, upload, file-transfer

I'm trying to [`FileTransfer.upload()`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to our test server which has a Self-Signed Certificate using Cordova 1.8.1

The following Code works fine on Android, but not on iOS.

```
var debug = true;
var uploadurl = "https://my.host.com/upload/file/here";
ft.upload(nImageURI, uploadurl, win2, fail, options, debug);
```

The `debug=true` in the upload method is an [undocumented debug feature](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/AdH6A21nRV8/W3I42mfV9qkJ).

I get the following Error only on iOS.  Android works Fine.

```
FileTransferError {
code = 3;
"http_status" = 0;
source = "https://my.host.com/upload/file/here";
target = "file:///var/mobile/Applications/1124016F-4FEE-400E-9AF1-2E2195EED1AF/myApp.app/www/index.html";
}
File Transfer Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be ‚Äúhttps://my.host.com/upload/file/hereÄù which could put your confidential information
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to add a whitelist to phonegap.plist (cordova.plist). Follow the instructions from [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).

Comment: @all who edited, it was my first attempt to give an answer to a question in Stackoverflow.com, thanks for making the answer more user-friendly.